# Error when add constraint in 2D Triangulation

Tags: c++, triangulation, cgal

I have some 2D constrained triangulation. When I add a constraint error occurs. This is my simple example for using it:

```
#include "stdafx.h"

#include <CGAL/Exact_predicates_inexact_constructions_kernel.h>
#include <CGAL/Constrained_Delaunay_triangulation_2.h>
#include <CGAL/Constrained_triangulation_plus_2.h>
#include <vector>
#include <fstream>

typedef CGAL::Exact_predicates_inexact_constructions_kernel K;
typedef CGAL::Triangulation_vertex_base_2<K>                     Vb;
typedef CGAL::Constrained_triangulation_face_base_2<K>           Fb;
typedef CGAL::Triangulation_data_structure_2<Vb,Fb>              TDS;
typedef CGAL::Exact_predicates_tag                               Itag;
typedef CGAL::Constrained_Delaunay_triangulation_2<K, TDS, Itag> CDT;
typedef CGAL::Constrained_triangulation_plus_2<CDT> CDTPlus;
typedef CDT::Constraint Constraint; 

typedef std::vector<Constraint> Constraints;

void load_data(const char* filename, Constraints &c)
{   
    std::fstream stream(filename, std::ios::in | std::ios::binary);     
    stream.seekp(0, std::fstream::end);
    std::streamoff size = stream.tellp() / sizeof(Constraint);
    stream.seekp(0, std::fstream::beg);
    c.resize((size_t)size); 
    stream.read(reinterpret_cast<char *>(&c.front()), sizeof(Constraint) * size);
}

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{   
    Constraints c;
    load_data("e:\\data.bin", c);

    CDTPlus cdt;
    // when i == 53376 - error      
    for (size_t i = 0; i < c.size(); ++i)       
        cdt.insert_constraint(c[i].first, c[i].second);         
    return 0;
}
```

That is my data.bin file [data.bin](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B341Tofyaa05ODZHZnZwbGlPUWc/edit?usp=sharing) 
That is my project [link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B341Tofyaa05UnUtMUNyYThmZTQ/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: Please edit your message so that the example code does compile. Currently we can hardly debug the issue.

Comment: I have changed the example and you can find it by the link in post

Comment: Can you please post the complete code of the first example, the one you said was failing?

Comment: Sorry, I had not understood that the second example was failing too.

Comment: It's the same data which I have used at the first example.

Comment: Do you have any ideas why it happens?

Comment: We are working on your data set, at GeometryFactory, but it is not the highest priority, actually (that is the support for MSVC 2013).

Answer (score 0):

The template class [`CGAL::Constrained_Delaunay_triangulation_2`](http://doc.cgal.org/latest/Triangulation_2/classCGAL_1_1Constrained__Delaunay__triangulation__2.html) has three template parameters. The default argument for the third one, `ITag`, is `CGAL::No_intersection_tag`. That means that the intersections of constraints is not handled.

Probably your input constraints do intersect.

Comment: I used CGAL::Exact_predicates_tag as ITag parameter.